# How to map the weight and calculate the product?

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

This is my pandas dataframe, I have to calculate the weight in a new column 'Value.

For example,
if the combination of columns (col1 col2 col3 col4) is 'Right_Wrong_Wrong_Right', then 'value' equals the product of
weight, the total value should be 5 x 100 x 100 x 100 = 5,000,000.

I can't think of any ways that will allow me to map the rules to calculate the product of the weight if not hard code.

Comment: Hello kpop, maybe someone read your question and understand it. I came to help and after reading it several times, still don't know what do you want to achieve. I would need more context. It will be also helpful if with the context of the problem (the output you want and how do you get to i), the dataframe in code is provided.

Comment: @Fernando hi, i've just amended it, could you help me to take a look again? thank you

Comment: How are in the shown dataframe the entries in the `U...` columns of a row related to the other columns? It looks like two independent dataframes glued to one.

Comment: Hi. Could you provide your dataframe as text rather than an image? Possibly following some of the tricks explained here: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: No weights for U1-U3 and U2-U4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, although I can't really test it since you posted your dataframe as an image rather than as text.

The right half of the dataframe is preprocessed into a python dict `weights` that maps each quadruple ('from', 'to', 'from_answer', 'to_answer') to the corresponding weight.

This dict is used to write a function `get_value` that can be used to calculate the value of each row.

You can apply this function to the dataframe using `.apply(get_value, axis=1)`.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

#df = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['u1', 'u1', 'u1', ...], 'to': ['u2', 'u2', 'u2', ...], 'from_answer': ['Right', 'Right', 'Wrong', ...], 'to_answer': ['Right', 'Wrong', 'Right', ...], 'weight': [30, 5, 1, ...], 'u1': ['Right']*3, 'u2': ['Right']*3, 'u3': ['Right', 'Right', 'Wrong', ...], 'u4': ['Right', 'Wrong', 'Right', ...]})

weights = {itemgetter('from', 'to', 'from_answer', 'to_answer')(row): row['weight'] for _,row in df.iterrows()}
# {('u1', 'u2', 'Right', 'Right'): 30, ('u1', 'u2', 'Right', 'Wrong'): 5, ('u1', 'u2', 'Wrong', 'Right'): 1, ...}

def get_value(row):
    return sum(weights[(u, v, row[u], row[v])] for u,v in (('u1', 'u2'), ('u2', 'u3'), ('u3', 'u4'), ('u1', 'u4')))

df['value'] = df.apply(get_value)
```